# Cast an IList to a Collection

Tags: c#, collections, ilist

I need to cast an `IList` to a `Collection` (`System.Collections.ObjectModel`)

How do you go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Collection<MyClass> coll = new Collection<MyClass>(myIList);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the constructor:

```
IList<T> myList = ...
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T> omc = 
           new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>(myList);
```